# Can't install apk made by Visual C++

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio

I installed into Visual Studio 2019, mobile development using C++, I created project with Native Activity template, then compiled tried to run on my phone but it didnt install, when i saw youtube video that guy made same thing as me but it did run in his case, i was trying to find anything on internet but there are only tutorials about Xamarin which is not my case, i'm absolutely hopeless, does anyone know any tutorials about this? Even Microsoft docs has almost no documentation about this

Comment: What was the issue when you tried to install it? Are you installing it with ADB?

Comment: I just took the apk, moved it to my phone(because emulator never started), and tried to install it and it just said "unable to install", i didnt use any ADB, as i said there are no tutorials for this so i really dont know how to set it up

Comment: Unless you try to install the apk via `adb install` from the PC you won't get an meaningful error message that may lead you to the error cause.

Comment: I tried the adb and it told me i have no enough space in phone which solved problem, but still got one more problem, it tells it's set to internal storage only, but idk how to change it, there is no documentation on how to change apk settings

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this is caused by the compiler settings.

If you still have your project / IDE open, try to check your compiler / linker settings to see if they match whatever the original project's were which you were following in this tutorial.

Sometimes, the people who make "setup" tutorials wont include these and just assume everyone automatically has the exact necessary instructions for the project-- but in some cases-- they wont, and then the person watching is left assume they did something incorrectly code-wise.

Without any code or other information to this post, this is possibly the most I can assist you with.

Best wishes.

~Fox

Comment: the man in tutorial just created new Native Activity project and then just run it, he didn't do anything other

Comment: Do you still have the video which you were using as a tutorial?

Comment: I noticed in the video he arms this for _"-25_arm_phone,"_ try using _"-25_x86_phone"_ in case, as I'm guessing the target could in minor cases cause some problems.

Comment: i tried all targets, but now i think i found problem, it seems like visual studio installed tools for Android up to version 7.1 but my phone is version 9.0 so i'll need to install it manually, i hope this will solve it

Comment: okay, i think i've installed and set up everything properly, but it still won't install, i think i'll be never able to do this